# WMIC enconding issue when run command from Linux

Tags: character-encoding, windows-10, interop, wmic, wql

I'm trying to get informations from a windows machine using WMIC in Linux.

Basically, my commands looks like below:

```
wmic '--authentication-file=/tmp/auth_file' '//127.0.0.1' 'SELECT Name FROM Win32_ComputerSystem'
```

The connection works fine and the results are correctly printed in the console. The problem is when the info has some type of encoding (like UserNames, for example). In these cases, I always get strange results.

With a quick search, I found [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210553/cmd-is-somehow-writing-chinese-text-as-output) [similar](https://superuser.com/questions/812438/combine-batch-wmic-ansi-unicode-output-formatting) [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503794/issue-with-batch-file-encoding) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599445/text-garble-in-batch-script-for-wmic-command) and the problem is the encoding of wmic output (that is UNICODE).

As suggested, I tried pipe the output to `more`, but it causes no effect.

My question is: Are there anyway to force the wmic output to ASCII or ISO-8859-1 when using it through Linux? Apparently, this is the only way to get the right character-enconding.

***UPDATE***

Just to add more infos.

The `wmic` command refers to a [linux client](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Wmic-linux) that uses WMI in a remote connection.

Since this command will be called through scripts (shell, php and python), I tried to make a encoding conversion inside a simple PHP code, but apparently, it does not work, 'cause the detected encode for the output is ISO-8859-1, and conversions for ASCII or UTF-8 simple doesn't work. below is a minimalist version of PHP script

```
//$cdm is a command like the example above
exec("$cmd", $out);
//also tried to parse $out and used just the string with the encoding problems in the functions below 
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($out, "CP850, UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, ASCII")); // it returns "ISO-8859-1"
var_dump(mb_convert_encoding($out, "ASCII", 'ISO-8859-1'));
var_dump(mb_convert_encoding($out, "UTF-8", 'ISO-8859-1'));
var_dump(mb_convert_encoding($out, "ISO-8859-1", 'UTF-8'));
```

**Info:**

- Linux: Debian 8
- Windows: Windows 10

Comment: @eryksun. Thanks for your explanation. Do you know any way to remote write my output to a file? I'll try to write it to a file and then execute the suggested `type` still using wmci, if possible.

Comment: Its a lInux [client](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Wmic-linux) that uses WMI.  Version 4.0. Is it a problem?

Comment: Yes, for me, since I've never used it. Based on a superficial scan of the code, I think it should talk to Windows using the native UTF-16 encoding and convert locally to UTF-8.

Comment: This is not possible, 'cause I don't have the control of Windows machine. Actually, this command will be called inside some scripts (shell, php and python) for different windows machines, so I can't configure each one of them. Thanks for the help, anyway.